# How to get piece of img src from div and compare in jquery

Tags: jquery, find, contains

Ok I know the title is a bit confusing but here is my problem: find all images containing image5.jpg and add a border to it. But I can not figure it out. Here is my code and below is the jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
<div class="picture"><img src="image.php/Marina/image5.jpg?width=650&height=650&image=/Marina/image5.jpg" /></div>
<div class="picture"><img src="image.php/Marina/image6.jpg?width=650&height=650&image=/Marina/image6.jpg" /></div>
<div class="picture"><img src="image.php/Marina/image7.jpg?width=650&height=650&image=/Marina/image7.jpg" /></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".picture img:contains('image5.jpg')").css("border", "1px solid black");​
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much. http://jsfiddle.net/7XUvw/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img[src*="image5.jpg"]', '.picture').css("border", "1px solid blue");​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7XUvw/12/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(".picture img[src*='image5.jpg']").css("border", "1px solid black");​
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [jQuery Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('.picture img[src*="image5.jpg"]').css("border", "1px solid black");​
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```
$(".picture img[src*='image5.jpg']").css("border", "1px solid black");​
```

should do it.